# Python: combine str.contains and merge in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that look somewhat like the following (the `Content` column in `df1` actually being the full content of an article and not, as in my example, only one sentence):

```
    PDF     Content
1   1234    This article is about bananas and pears and grapes, but also mentions apples and oranges, so much fun!
2   1111    Johannes writes about apples and oranges and that's great.
3   8000    Content that cannot be matched to the anything in df1.    
4   3993    There is an interesting piece on bananas plus kiwis as well.
    ...
```

(Total: 5709 entries)

```
    Author        Title
1   Johannes      Apples and oranges
2   Peter         Bananas and pears and grapes
3   Hannah        Bananas plus kiwis
4   Helena        Mangos and peaches
    ...
```

(Total: 10228 entries)

I would like to merge both dataframes by searching for the `Title` from `df2` in the `Content` of `df1`. If the title appears somewhere in the **first 2500 characters** of the content, it is a match.
Note: it is important that **all** entries from `df1` are preserved. In contrast, I only want to keep the entries from `df2` that are matched (i.e. a left join).
Note: all `Titles` are unique values.

Desired output (column sequence doesn't matter):

```
    Author     Title                        PDF     Content
1   Peter      Bananas and pears and grapes 1234    This article is about bananas and pears and grapes, but also mentions apples and oranges, so much fun!
2   Johannes   Apples and oranges           1111    Johannes writes about apples and oranges and that's great.
3   NaN        NaN                          8000    Content that cannot be matched to the anything in df2.    
4   Hannah     Bananas plus kiwis           3993    There is an interesting piece on bananas plus kiwis as well.
    ...
```

I think I need a combination between `pd.merge` and `str.contains`, but I can't figure out how!

Comment: What behavior do you want/expect if there are multiple matches?

Comment: All the entries in the Title column are unique. Regarding the Content column, I want the Title entry to match the first found match in the Content entry.

Comment: "First found match" as in...? First in the dataset (row by row) or first in terms of position in the string?

Comment: Try a full cartesian join then design your own filter?

Comment: I've edited my question, see PDF 1234, mentioning both 'bananas and pears and grapes' AND 'apples and oranges'. So, first in terms of position in the string. Though I must say it is highly unlikely that two Titles will both appear in the first 2500 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: the solution could be slow :).
1. get list for title
2. create index for df1 based on title list order
3. concat df1 and df2 on idx

```
  lst = [item.lower() for item in df2.Title.tolist()]
  end = len(lst)
  def func(row):
    content = row[:2500].lower()
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
      if item in content:
        return i
    end += 1
    return end
  df1 = df1.assign(idx=df1.Content.apply(func))

  res = pd.concat([df1.set_index('idx'), df2], axis=1)
```

output

```
      PDF                                            Content    Author  \
0  1111.0  Johannes writes about apples and oranges and t...  Johannes
1  1234.0  This article is about bananas and pears and gr...     Peter
2  3993.0  There is an interesting piece on bananas plus ...    Hannah
3     NaN                                                NaN    Helena
4  8000.0  Content that cannot be matched to the anything...       NaN

                          Title
0            Apples and oranges
1  Bananas and pears and grapes
2            Bananas plus kiwis
3            Mangos and peaches
4                           NaN
```

Comment: I get the following error, even though initially, both dataframes only have non-null objects:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-9e8ebf20b2d3> in <module>()
      2 # in the first 2500 characters of the second df.
      3 
----> 4 lst = [item.lower() for item in df2.Title.tolist()]
      5 end = len(lst)
      6 def func(row):

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'.
Any idea?

Comment: @NynkeLys change the Content  to str

Comment: I have, with the following command, but still get the same error: df1.Content = df1.Content.astype('str')

Comment: @NynkeLys convert title to str

Comment: @NynkeLys To run the code, title and content have to be string. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I get the following error message: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 11), indices imply (6, 7). I use Python 2.7, could that be it? @galaxyan

Comment: @NynkeLys it is duplication issue. Do you need Author without PDF in final dataframe?

Comment: I need all columns in my final dataframe, so PDF, Author, Title and Content! @galaxyan

Comment: @NynkeLys I added one line to code. It may fix the issue you have

Comment: Unfortunately... I get this message: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'end' referenced before assignment. Thanks so much for helping out @galaxyan

Comment: did you assign the end as length of author list before you use it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Tried adding 'end' as global inside func, but that doesn't do the trick either. InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. @galaxyan

Comment: @NynkeLys  you can use duplicated to find which idxs are duplicated

Comment: I did that already, there are no duplicated idxs. I can't move the discussion to chat unfortunately, that'd make it easier for me to show you... @galaxyan

Comment: @NynkeLys my suggestion is you could try sample first to see

Answer (score -1):

You could do a full cartesian join / cross product, then filter. Since you couldn't do a hash lookup, it shouldn't be any slower than the equivalent "Join" statement:

```
df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 2
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key')
df3['key'] = df3.apply(lambda row: row['Title'].lower() in row['Content'][:2500].lower(), axis=1)
df3 = df3.loc[df3['key'], ['PDF', 'Author', 'Title', 'Content']]
```

Which produces the table:

```
       PDF    Author                         Title  \
0   1234.0  Johannes            Apples and oranges
1   1234.0     Peter  Bananas and pears and grapes
4   1111.0  Johannes            Apples and oranges
14  3993.0    Hannah            Bananas plus kiwis

                                              Content
0   This article is about bananas and pears and gr...
1   This article is about bananas and pears and gr...
4   Johannes writes about apples and oranges and t...
14  There is an interesting piece on bananas plus ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but got the following error: ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series. Any idea?

Comment: Any idea? Running your code gives a constant error. I use Python 2.7, even when using the exact same dfs as the one I created for my question.